# Show variables and data labels with CCA package (vegan)

Tags: r, ggplot2, vegan

I want to do a CCA plot between environmental factors and species abundance of different sites with `vegan`. I realized this code :

```
library(vegan)
library(ggvegan)
Species <- read.table("C:/Users/mathi/Documents/VegCCA2.txt", head = TRUE, row.names = 1)
fact <- read.table("C:/Users/mathi/Documents/ParamCCA2.txt", head = TRUE, row.names = 1)
cca.plants<-cca(Species, fact)
autoplot(cca.plants)
```

(VegCCA2 --> Species) represents plant species (each column is a species =195 species) and (ParamCCA2 --> fact) represents environmental factors (each column is a factor = 6 factors) for each site (each site is a line = 69).

But I have a problem, all values of first environmental factor are represented on the triplot and not the others environmental factors:

[image: CCA triplot]

My question is : How can I considerate all environmental factors on my triplot and display just one variable by factor like this :
[image: CCA triplot example]

One other problem, the species labels do not display on the triplot, I tried with the function `text()` but I didn't successed.

Comment: It would be easier to help if the problem was reproducible. Please consider either adding enough of the data with `dput(Species)`, or showing the problem with one of the built-in datasets such as `dune`

Comment: @RichardTelford Thank you for your help i managed to fix the problems with variables with the function 'dput' (i left commas between numbers = french numbers), now the problem is the points labels. I tried to reduce the number of species on the board and the names of species appeared on the plot. I think the problem is the number of species (195 species). Do you know if there is a function to include an infinite number of species?